# Migrating repo from bitbucket to Github giving pre-receive hook declined error

Tags: github

I am trying to migrate the repo from bitbucket to GitHub but getting the error "pre-receive hook declined".

Tired these two methods:

1st:

```
git clone --mirror https://bitbucket.org/exampleuser/repository-to-mirror.git

cd repository-to-mirror.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/exampleuser/mirrored

git push --mirror
```

2nd:
In the import code option, paste the Bitbucket repo's URL but still not able to import. Got " There was an error pushing commits to GitHub." error

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue. No solution yet.